# How to configure ExecutionPolicy as "RemoteSigned" in Powershell 4.0 api

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, executionpolicy

I need to configure ExecutionPolicy as 'RemoteSigned' at initial session state or somehow before execution of script. I don't want to execute script to set policy. This would alter the policy at client machine which i don't want.

In Powershell 5.0 reference assemblies one can do easily,

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned
```

but how can I achieve the same while remaining with Powershell 4.0 as referenced assemblies.

**C# code to execute script**

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned; --> this is OK for Powershell ReferenceAssemblies 5.0 but not 4.0

iss.ImportPSModule(new[] { typeof(Parameter).Assembly.Location });
using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create(iss))
{
     var psScript = _inlineScript ?? File.ReadAllText(_path);
     powerShell.AddScript(psScript);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean when you launch PowerShell?  if so can you do this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned ... rest of parameters here
```

I know we have several scripts that start out this way.

Comment: No no. I don't want to run Windows Powershell at all.
I want to set it from C# code before executing script using PowerShell api.. See the edit above

Comment: You may have answered your own question if you are asking how to call an API that isn't available to you.  You can't.  I must not understand your question.  This answer does not change the user profile setting, it's only effective for this invocation of PowerShell.

Comment: Can I ask one question what happens when I run the following code.

using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create(iss))
{
          string script = "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"; 
     powerShell.AddScript(script);
   var putput = powerShell.Invoke();
}